# ERROR: expected expression before "{"

Tags: c

The second line in the function triggers the error.

```
void read_word(int counts[25])  
{   
    counts[25]={0};  
    int b;  
    char a;  
    scanf("%c", &a);  
    while(isalpha(a) )  
    {  
        b= a -97;  
        counts[b]++;  
        scanf("%c", &a);  
    } 
}
```

Comment: We speak English here :)

Comment: lol. sorry I edited it when realized)

Comment: Vladimir . thanks for editing

Comment: What exactly you're trying to do? Initialize the whole array `counts` with zeros or make the last element `0`?

Comment: I am trying to initialize the whole array with zeros

Comment: The "`array = {0}`" construct *only* works during an array declaration, such as `int counts[] = {1,2,3,4,0};` or `int counts[25] = {0};`.

Comment: Thanks everyone I have no errors anymore.....

Comment: I cleared the array with for loop. I know it is pretty long but anyways it works

Comment: Again I run this with no error in gcc 4.4.5. Is this gcc this well implemented?

Comment: @Ziyao - it's not "well implemented". On gcc 4.4.5 it just assignes the value `0` only to the first element of the array, not for all elements. You've been mislead by another thing - the `0`. Try with `13`, for example, to see that only the first element will be `13`

Comment: @Kiril Kirov  Thanks! Then I guess it is pretty arbitrary implemented then.

Comment: @Kiril: in C there is no such thing as "partial initialization". An object either is fully initialized or not initialized at all. In the absence of an initializer, the value used is 0 of the proper type. In `int count[3] = {4};` the 1st element is initialized with `4`, the other 2 elements with `0`;

Comment: @pmg - in C standard - no (and I haven's say such thing), but in `gcc` - it seems like there is :) `int x[50]; x = {13}; cout << x[3] << x[0];` prints `013` in my `gcc 4.5.2` ;)

Comment: @Kiril: I don't know C++. In C, your example is bogus: `x` by itself cannot be use on the left side of an assignment. Also it shows the value of x[3] to be 0: meaning the element was initialized. I wrote a [test program on ideone](http://ideone.com/XMnro) to see the differences.

Comment: @pmg - OK, right..I tested for C++, sorry (:

Answer (score 5):

You cannot initialize the array not during declaration: (`counts[25]={0};`).

Also, this: `void read_word(int counts[25])` is treated as `void read_word(int *counts)` which means the compiler will not know what is the size of the array...